# MS Dynamics CRM error HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, soapui

I am trying to call Microsoft Dynamics CRM web service CustomBinding_IOrganizationService and the SOAPAction is Retrieve using SOAP UI

I am using NTLM authentication type

```
SOAPAction - http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Retrieve


Accept - application/xml, text/xml, */*

Content-Type - text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Below is my xml request

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services" xmlns:con="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:Retrieve>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:entityName>contact</ser:entityName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:id>B1180AE1-19F5-E011-820D-00505610126C</ser:id>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:columnSet>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <con:AllColumns>false</con:AllColumns>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <con:Columns>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <arr:string>fullname</arr:string>
            </con:Columns>
         </ser:columnSet>
      </ser:Retrieve>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am getting below response

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
>
> Cache-Control: private
>
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>
> Persistent-Auth: true
>
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>
> Date: Tue, 07 May 2019 15:01:34 GMT
>
> Bad Request

Can you please help me to correct where the issue is?

Comment: Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved as the service was down during that period